# Swift checking String for guid value

Tags: ios, swift

I receive from my web service an authorisation string, that represents a Guid (C#). How I can convert string into guid using Swift? Or, how I can validate result, that it is, in fact, a Guid?

```
var str1:String = "5810744d-49f7-4edc-aefb-ecd1ebf9e59b"
var str2:String = "Some text"
```

How i can define - is string contains guid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` with a regex to see if a string is in the correct format:

```
var str1:String = "(5810744d-49f7-4edc-aefb-ecd1ebf9e59b)"
var str2:String = "Some text"

let guidPred = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "((\\{|\\()?[0-9a-f]{8}-?([0-9a-f]{4}-?){3}[0-9a-f]{12}(\\}|\\))?)|(\\{(0x[0-9a-f]+,){3}\\{(0x[0-9a-f]+,){7}0x[0-9a-f]+\\}\\})")

// Prints "str1 IS a GUID"
if guidPred.evaluateWithObject(str1) {
    println("str1 IS a GUID")
} else {
    println("str1 is NOT a GUID")
}

// Prints "str2 is NOT a GUID"
if guidPred.evaluateWithObject(str2) {
    println("str2 IS a GUID")
} else {
    println("str2 is NOT a GUID")
}
```

This regex will match any of the four formats listed on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx). To keep it (relatively) simple, the expression will match some ill-formatted strings (such as if you were to delete one hyphen, but not all the others: `5810744d49f7-4edc-aefb-ecd1ebf9e59b`), but will filter out regular text.